# How can I get start time using Activiti Engine?

Tags: java, time, activiti

I need to get a start time using Activiti.Than use with timeCycle.
How can I do that?

I can get endTime this way, but I couldn't find how to get start time.

```
<timerEventDefinition>
    <timeCycle activiti:endDate="2015-02-25T16:42:11+00:00">R3/PT10H</timeCycle>
</timerEventDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can doing following way:

Date dateTime = getRuntimeService().createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId().singleResult().getStartTime();

Best Regards